# Log File in unix gets over written

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am using the below code to run some commands and also log the output for a script.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1>/home/log/log.out 2>&1

echo "Before Execution: $(date)"

Some commands 

echo "After Execution:$(date)"
```

The code works fine and the logs are generated for the run. However, It does so in an overwrite mode. Everytime the log file gets overwritten with the logs of that current execution. I want all the execution logs to be stored in append mode in the log.out file.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Open (replace) the file descriptor `1` for appending instead: `exec 1>>/home/log/log.out`

Comment: `>` overwrites, `>>` appends.